# WebAssembly code not running in existing angularjs app

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

I have written code in rust and webAssembly and playing around it , where I am facing some issue.

**lib.rs** file

```
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern {
    pub fn alert(s: &str);
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet(name: &str) {
    alert(&format!("Hello, {}!", name));
}
```

Built above file to **wasm** using **cargo** and deployed to NPM registry.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@livspace-3d/hello-wasm

Now , I have installed the same npm module into my application using `npm i <package_name>`

Getting error while using the wasm file in index.html code , here is the code :

```
      <script>
            function fetchAndInstantiate() {  
                    fetch('./static/js/hello-wasm/pkg/hello_wasm_bg.wasm').then(response =>
                         response.arrayBuffer()
                    ).then(bytes =>{
                        console.error("I am herer2", JSON.stringify(bytes));
                        return WebAssembly.compile(bytes) 
                    }).then(mod =>{
                        console.error("I am herer3", mod);
                        mod.greet("WebAssembly");
                    });
                }
                fetchAndInstantiate();
        <script>
```

**Console prints:**

[image]

Comment: `wasm-bindgen` is commonly used with `wasm-pack` to generate a JavaScript module to deal with non-trivial function calls not supported by pure WebAssembly (which includes most function calls), so are you sure you don't want to import that instead of importing the wasm module directly?

Comment: `wasm-pack` also generating `.wasm`file which should be in pure webAssembly, I may be wrong.Anyhow,  I want to execute `greet` into my application

Comment: Yes, but the `.wasm` file isn't generated to be suitable for direct consumption. `wasm-bindgen` does some manipulations to the wasm module, and generates JavaScript code to wrap it, to get around some of the current shortcomings of WebAssembly, including, for instance, the fact that pure WebAssembly only supports integers as parameters and return types. So in most cases you'll have to use the JavaScript file instead of the WebAssembly module directly.

Comment: OK . On using .js file I am getting this `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript, CSS MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Comment: Change code to this  `const js = import("./static/js/hello-wasm/pkg/hello_wasm.js");
                js.then(js => {
                    js.greet("WebAssembly");
                });`

Comment: Getting this error also : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module`